# Cohen's kappa in r package irr

Tags: r, statistics

I tried this simple test case:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = as.factor(c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b")),
                 x2 = as.factor(c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b")))
```

The ratings are identical 4 out of 5 times, the estimated chance agreement is 1/2. I put the numbers into the  simple formula from the wikipedia page:

```
(k <- (4/5 - 1/2) / (1 - 1/2))
[1] 0.6
```

But the kappa2 function from the package irr gives me:

```
irr::kappa2(df)
 Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: unweighted)

 Subjects = 5 
   Raters = 2 
    Kappa = 0.545 

        z = 1.37 
  p-value = 0.171
```

The default option for 'weight' is 'unweighted', so why is the result here different from my manual approach? Is some adjustment involved, that is not documented in the help page for the function? Or did I somehow messed up the formula for Cohen's kappa?

Comment: Why is the estimated chance agreement equal to 1/2?

Comment: I assumed there is a 50% chance of agreement, because there are two possible outcomes ("a" and "b"). But the estimated chance of agreement is computed like Maurits Evers has shown in his comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calculating kappa incorrectly.

Take another look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa), specifically the example they give.

Here is a worked-through example showing the same intermediate steps for illustration purposes but based on your data.

```
table(df)
#   x2
#x1  a b
#  a 3 1
#  b 0 1

p0 <- (3 + 1) / (3 + 1 + 1 + 0)
pa <- (3 + 1) / (3 + 1 + 1 + 0) * (3 + 0) / (3 + 1 + 1 + 0)
pb <- (0 + 1) / (3 + 1 + 1 + 0) * (1 + 1) / (3 + 1 + 1 + 0)
pe <- pa + pb
kappa <- (p0 - pe) / (1 - pe)
#[1] 0.5454545
```

The value agrees exactly with the one `irr::kappa2` reports.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.